# GIT - Pull requests from the same branch bring over history of commits

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, pull-request

This is the setup in one of my repositories:

- `master` branch <- this is always in the production server
- `staging` branch (default branch) <- this is in the staging server

Every change we make goes through the following steps.
Let's say I have to make a change to `readme.md`.

1. I create a new branch from the default branch (`staging`), let's call it `patch-readme`
2. I make all the changes I need in `patch-readme`.
3. When I'm happy with my changes, I create a PR to `staging`.
4. I merge (squash and merge) the PR and then I delete `patch-readme`.

   - (note: multiple developers could push to the `staging` branch at this point, following the previous steps)
5. `staging` branch is then deployed to the staging server.
6. If I'm happy with the changes in the staging server, I create a new PR from `staging` to `master`.
7. I then review the changes and I merge (squash and merge) the pull request.
8. At this point I merge `master` back into `staging`. I am doing this because if the next PR to `staging` has a change to the `readme.md` file, when I create the new PR from `staging` to `master` I am getting a conflict on that file. So to avoid conflicts I am merging back `master` after every merged PR.

There is a problem with this workflow, basically every pull request from `staging` to `master` is bringing in commits from months ago, meaning a mess in the repository (for example if there is a commit that references one issue, that issue will have a very long list of references, one for every new PR created).

Now, something I don't understand is that sometimes (I haven't figured out under what circumstances) that history gets cleaned up. Today it happened to me because a developer forgot to update from `master` after merging a PR and I had to fix a few conflicts, after fixing the conflicts the new PR had a clean history. I've tried to replicate this scenario but it doesn't seem to do the same.

I've had a look at rebase, so what I've tried after merging the PR from `staging` to `master`, instead of merging back `master` I ran a `git rebase master` while on the `staging` branch. This didn't work, the next PR to `master` still had previous history.

Something that worked is that instead of creating a PR to `master`, I ran

```
git checkout master
git rebase staging
```

In this case I didn't have to do anything and the next PR the history was clean. But this doesn't make a lot of sense because we'll need to discard the PRs. We're using PRs for code review.

What am I doing wrong? How can I have every time a clean history in the PR from `staging` to `master`?

Just a note here, our developers usually use only **Github Desktop** and the **Github web interface**. And because we're a small team everybody is able to create and merge PRs to both `staging` and `master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why that was happening. We're using the GitHub web UI to merge PRs.

Basically every PR sent to staging was merged with a "Squash and merge".
The PR from staging to master was merged the same way.

By using a "Merge commit" instead of "Squash and merge" every commit in staging is also appearing in master (instead of a single commit with the squash).

So, now to keep the history clean we're doing a "Squash and merge" from the feature branch to staging, while we're doing a "Merge commit" from staging to master.

Hope this is helpful to somebody else.